# Can we prove that plane waves form a complete basis of solutions to the wave equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

For the 3D wave equation,
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial^{2} \textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)}{\partial t^{2}}-\frac{1}{v^{2}}\nabla^{2}\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)=0,
\end{equation}
can we prove that plane waves,
\begin{equation}
    \textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)=e^{-i(\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{r}-\omega t)},
\end{equation}
form a complete basis of solutions to this equation?

Comment: You need the Fourier (transform) inversion theorem, with that it should be quite simple.

Comment: Making $\omega = \|k\| v$ and considering $\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^{2} \textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)}{\partial t^{2}}-\nabla^{2}\textbf{A}(\textbf{r},t)=0,
\end{equation}$ instead, by direct substitution.